# How to say that a proposed date/time is OK without sounding condescending?

Tags: keigo, formality, written-language

In a very formal context, how to answer properly when an unknown person who is *hugely* higher than you in the hierarchy (a recruiter, an N+3, an official, etc.) invites you to some unexpected event/lunch/interview/ceremony and suggests a date and time which turn out to be OK? I always struggle with this. Actually, I think it is even easier to say politely that the suggested time is *not* OK.

I refrain from using 大丈夫です or いいです because it seems overly familiar to me. So, most of the time, I end up with such a circumlocution as

> どうもありがとうございます。金曜日なら結構です。

just to say *’you proposed Friday, and this is OK’*. I don’t know if 都合がよいです or is other sentences with 都合 are OK in this context. I don’t want to end up saying to a minister *’yeah, so you wanna meet me next Monday? I’m quite busy man, but I checked my schedule and it looks rather feasible’*.

NB: this is a question about formal and especially formal written Japanese—before anyone says *’you can just send 大丈夫 with the poop emoji and he will understand’*, of course he will understand, I agree with this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to be careful with 結構です -- it's more often used to politely say "no thank you" than "that's fine", and using it in the latter sense requires some shoring up of the sentence to eliminate any ambiguity.

I don't think you need to mention the time/schedule explicitly. Depending on the relationship and the nature of the invitation, any of the following might do:

- かしこまりました。(Probably most useful when the "invitation" can't really be refused, such as when a recruiter tells you your interview is at 10:00 on Monday.)
- この度はご招待いただき、ありがとうございました。喜んで参加させていただきます。If the difference in status is extreme, you might go with 身に余る光栄でございます。謹んで参加させていただきます, but that would probably be excessive unless the circumstances were very special.
- ◯◯へのご招待、ありがとうございます。是非行かせていただきたいと思います。

Explicitly mentioning that you'll be attending because you're free on the day could imply that you're only going because you've got nothing better to do, so I think you're better off with an appropriately polite version of "Thank you for inviting me. It will be a pleasure to attend." If, for some reason, you must mention the time, I'd suggest phrasing it as a confirmation of the time:

- 金曜日の◯◯時ですね。わかりました。宜しくお願い致します。

Just a few ideas, but you'll need to adapt them, and their level of politeness, to the actual situation (and whether you're speaking or replying in writing).

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for catching those typos. I proably, er probably, shoudn't try to write detailed answers after a long day at work...

Comment: Does saying something like "10日10:00は完璧です。" sound good to accept an interview?